# How to get validation box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am validating a field before the button is clicked, and want to show the browser validation box like the picture below. I am not using a form
so not sure how to get this validation box.
[image]

```
 validate =  async () => {
      const bool =  await this.props.validateUsername().then(res => {
        return res;
      });
      if(bool){
        //show validation message
      }  
    }
```

Input element:

```
const username = <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="ENTER USERNAME" onChange={this.validate}/>
```

Comment: You could probably do this via the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using html validation. To match a validation like lowercase letters, you can use:

```html
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="[a-z]" title="Username should only contain lowercase letters"><br><br>
```

You don't need javascript / React validation for achieve this.

Take care with prevent default, you'll need a submit button:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="[a-z]" title="Username should only contain lowercase letters"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afoone/by5ecz9g/2/)

My personal advice is not to use html validation and create for your own a validation, or use some react validation library.